# CSS nav bar current page color alteration

Tags: css, nav

I'm trying to make it so that I can add a class to the link for the current page and the background will stay filled in teal (As it would when hovered)

However, as it is at the moment, the link text is displaying in the teal still(pic part 1), even though the css says display it white (pic part 2)

the css I have is:

```
#nav a:link, a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #066;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover, a:active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav a.selected:link, a.selected:active{
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav a.selected:hover, a.selected:active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}
```

the html is

```
<div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="" class="selected">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONSULTANCY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SUPPORT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>

            </ul>
            </div>
```

[image: Nav Bar]

When I inspect the element in firefox, its showing that the color should be white. So it should be showing correctly, but it's not. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've cleared cache and that didnt sort it.

Comment: did you try adding a.selected:visited in your block with white color? As after you click it, it is "visited"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
#nav a.selected:link, a.selected:active {
```

to this

```
#nav a.selected:link, a.selected:visited{
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pmg0wxjm/)

You are tried to set active twice.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... thanks! It's fixed now!

Answer (score 2):

You have styled all the states for the `selected` item but not the default just add the selector for the item without state:

> #### #nav a.selected, #nav a.selected:link, a.selected:active

```css
#nav a:link,
a:visited {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #066;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover,
a:active {
  display: block;
  background-color: #066;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav a.selected, #nav a.selected:link,
a.selected:active {
  display: block;
  background-color: #066;
  color: #fff;
}
#nav a.selected:hover,
a.selected:active {
  display: block;
  background-color: #066;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="selected">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SOLUTIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">CONSULTANCY</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">SUPPORT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:active` is a `state` but `:link` not. Link is referring to the attr of the anchor so

Change

```
#nav a.selected:link, a.selected:active
```

to

`#nav a[href].selected, a.selected:active`

```css
#nav a:link, a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #066;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover, a:active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav a[href].selected, a.selected:active{
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav a.selected:hover, a.selected:active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #066;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="" class="selected">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SOLUTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONSULTANCY</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Really? 6k rep and you don't even explain your answer? Oh dear.

Comment: @Danko `href` is the same as `link` but in this case it focus more on the anchor itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Simply change this  css `#nav a.selected:link, a.selected:active`   with `#nav a.selected, a.selected:active` and your problem will solve

Comment: You did not changed anything.

Comment: See this `nav a.selected:link`

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry. But in that case, no need to `a.selected:active`